# How to add/replace text inside a textbox in MS Excel through C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have this excel form which consist textboxes and I want my program to be able to fill up the textboxes but I can't find any reference on how to do that. The next option in my mind is to put a defined text inside the textboxes and just use `.replace` option with interop but excel can't seem to replace text inside textboxes. Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: text cell content, or actual text boxes?

Comment: yes. if you wanted to add string into the cell content then definately you need to you the interop. You can drop the normal windows form controls and then access it like normal windows form

Comment: the actual textboxes. or those which are considered shapes

Answer (score -1):

Try a library like EPPlus!

Here is the [link](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

Specifically, see a list of examples on how to use the library
[here](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ContentSheetExample)